# Active link background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to keep a background image for active link and hover 
for a navigational bar on this site

**Sitelink:** `http://67.23.226.231/~edutubei/onepage/#about`

using below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navigation a[href^="#' + location.pathname.split("#")[1] + '"]').addClass('current'); 
});
```

with the below css

```
ul.navigation .current{
  background:url(../images/current_page.png) no-repeat right bottom;
}    
ul.navigation .current a, ul.navigation .current a:hover{
  color:#FFF;
}
```

but this is not working how can i keep a background image/highlight the active and hover links

Comment: It might help to post an example.  The sitelink doesn't work.

Comment: is `navigation` an `id` or a `class`? Your CSS should read `a.current` if your javascript is meant to be adding the class to the link

Comment: Link corrected  -- thnks @anthony

Comment: pls check the link now @lucuma

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not right. It should be '.navigation' in place of '#navigation'

The location.pathname returns only /~edutubei/onepage/. so you got to use window.location.href instead.

```
 $('.navigation a[href="#' + window.location.href.split("#")[1] + '"]').addClass('current');
```

Comment: You sure ? I used the same code on the website you gave. And it worked over there. An orange triangle appeared next to Nosotros. Which browser are you trying.

Comment: <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.navigation a[href="#' + window.location.href.split("#")[1] + '"]').addClass('current');});</script>  this what i added  pls see the link    view-source:http://67.23.226.231/~edutubei/onepage/#about